# i686-cm-linux-gcc: Command not found

Tags: gcc, openwrt, cross-compilation

While cross compiling OpenWRT, I have I have replaced OpenWRT's toolchain with toolchain i686 architecture. But, I am getting below mentioned error:

```
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/hclintel/pankaj/fresh/trunk/build_dir/target-i386_i486_musl-1.1.10/linux-x86_generic/linux-3.18.18'
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: i686-cm-linux-gcc: command not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: i686-cm-linux-gcc: command not found
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/hclintel/pankaj/fresh/trunk/build_dir/target-i386_i486_musl-1.1.10/linux-x86_generic/linux-3.18.18'
arch/x86/Makefile:114: stack-protector enabled but compiler support broken
Makefile:657: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler
make[5]: i686-cm-linux-gcc: Command not found
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/bin/sh: 1: i686-cm-linux-gcc: not found
make[6]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
make[5]: *** [prepare0] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/hclintel/pankaj/fresh/trunk/build_dir/target-i386_i486_musl-1.1.10/linux-x86_generic/linux-3.18.18'
make[4]: *** [/home/hclintel/pankaj/fresh/trunk/build_dir/target-i386_i486_musl-1.1.10/linux-x86_generic/linux-3.18.18/.modules] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/hclintel/pankaj/fresh/trunk/target/linux/x86'
make[3]: *** [compile] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/hclintel/pankaj/fresh/trunk/target/linux'
make[2]: *** [target/linux/compile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hclintel/pankaj/fresh/trunk'
make[1]: *** [/home/hclintel/pankaj/fresh/trunk/staging_dir/target-i386_i486_musl-1.1.10/stamp/.target_compile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hclintel/pankaj/fresh/trunk'
make: *** [world] Error 2
hclintel@hclintel-ThinkCentre-M73:~/pankaj/fresh/trunk$
```

When I run `echo $PATH`, then I get below mentioned result:

```
/home/hclintel/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

I think I need to modify path in configuration file but I am not able to find the right place to modify path.

Comment: Did you try to do a `locate i686-cm-linux-gcc` to see if you have the executable on your system ? (better do an `updatedb` as root before).

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to locate where i686-cm-linux-gcc exists.

2) How are you building OpenWRT? I'm guessing through Make. 
For that you need to edit the Makefile and add the path there. 
There should be a statement in one of the Makefiles where they are assigning the compiler.

Change

```
CC=i686-cm-linux-gcc
```

to

```
CC=/path/to/i686-cm-linux-gcc
```